# Core data one-to-one relationship updates

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an `Item` and `Color` classes. All object are fetched from server. I have a request to fetch all items and all colors. Every item have an `id` to `Color`.

```
class Color: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: Int
    @NSManaged var name: String
}


class Item: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: Int
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var color: Color
}
```

What is the best way to synchronize this two list in DB using Core Data?

1. I can use one-to-one relationship but then I cannot simply remove all `Colors` and save all received from server, because Core Data is using own IDs. Probably I should find all colors and update them, also remove all not existing.
2. I can use `fetched properties`
3. I can save in db `color_id`, and manually search Color

Comment: So your issue is importing data and managing duplicates? What version of iOS do you need to support and how are you importing?

Comment: Yes generaly, I'm using ios8 and I'm importing by http requests, as I wrote 2 http requests first with colors, second with items

Comment: Have you considered using something like RestKit?

Comment: I'm using SwiftyJSON and Alamofire, I think this tools will allow more flexibility

Answer (score 0):

You should make the relationship bi-directional, always, as this helps Core Data to manage itself properly. Then, you need to run a fetch request for the new data you're importing to decide if you need to update or create. You can, depending on the size of data you're importing, create a mapping of existing color ids to managed object ids so you don't need to do lots of fetches, this makes the import more efficient.